# How can I make the lettering of items taken from the palette in Android Studio smaller?

Tags: android, palette

I'm designing a screen using the designer in Android Studio.  When I place an ImageView on the screen, the characters are much too large.  Is there any way to make them smaller?  Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: I can see textAlignment and textDirection but no TextSize.

Comment: Sorry, bad reading, you mean `ImageView`. If you want it smaller give it `layout_width` and `layout_height` values.
Because maybe your setting the text to match the parent and then it takes the height os the image too.

Comment: All of the ImageViews have layout_height and layout_width values already.

Comment: I did a test and noticed that the size of the ImageView text is dependent on the width of the ImageView.